# Сделать снимок экрана с помощью Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, appium

Кто-нибудь знает, можно ли сделать скриншот с помощью Selenium WebDriver? Пытался реализовать так:

```
File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("D:\\jobs\\KBL\\screenshots\\screenshot.png"));
```

Но, пишет что `FileUtils` не может быть разрешен.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Этот класс `FileUtils` находится в библиотеке `commons-io-2.2.jar`. Если вы используете maven то следующая зависимость используется

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons.io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commonsIO</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```